# Xamarin. Forms IOS 11 App Names displaying as single word

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I noticed in iOS 11 when I build an app the name is displayed as a single word for example "AppName"  rather than "App Name".

This happens even though the name is specified as two words in the manifest.

Any way around it?

Comment: Can you share your info.plist? I test on my side with iOS11, it works fine.

Comment: It's been a while since you posted this - did you get it resolved? (Am having this problem too.)